# Google Cloud Datastore 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'email'

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

When I try getting a kind from my datastore it returns NoneType, as if the query is empty. I know the datastore is working properly while saving, but pulling a kind from the a query is not.

Also using the GQL Query in the Google cloud Console website and using `SELECT * FROM User` does return all the kinds. User kind has no parents, it is at the root. I made sure all the properties are indexed as well.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong on GET.

**MyApp.py**

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.db import GqlQuery


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        message = self.request.body
        message = message.splitlines()

        if message[0] == "register":
            user = User.create_user(message[1], message[2], message[3])
            user_key = User.save_user(user)
            if user_key is not None:
                self.response.write(user_key)

        else:
            user = User.get_by_id(User.email == message[0])
            if User.token == message[1]:
                self.response.write("CURRENT")
            else:
                User.token = message[1]
                User.save_user(user)
                self.response.write("UPDATED")

    def get(self):
        self.response.write("CONNECTED")
        user= User.query().get()
        self.response.write("\n" + query.email)


class User(ndb.Model):
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    token = ndb.StringProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, email, token, name):
        user = User(email=email, token=token, name=name, id=email)
        return user

    @classmethod
    def save_user(cls, user):
        user_key = user.put()
        return user_key

    @classmethod
    def get_user(cls, email):
        return User.get_by_id(User.email == email)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what was wrong. So there seems to be an issue with the way Google Cloud SDK is set up on my computer. When running the same code on the google servers rather than on my network everything seems to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing `.get_by_id()` with a query.

The `get_by_id` method is actually mapped to `ndb.Model._get_by_id` which invokes `ndb.Model._get_by_id_async`, which requires an entity key identifier to determine the entity's key used to do a *direct entity lookup* (not a query!). From `appengine.ext.ndb.model.py`:

> ```
>   @classmethod
>   @utils.positional(3)
>   def _get_by_id_async(cls, id, parent=None, app=None, namespace=None,
>                        **ctx_options):
>     """Returns an instance of Model class by ID (and app, namespace).
>
>     This is the asynchronous version of Model._get_by_id().
>     """
>     key = Key(cls._get_kind(), id, parent=parent, app=app, namespace=namespace)
>     return key.get_async(**ctx_options)
> ```

But in your code you're passing as `id` a bool: `User.email == message[0]`, which most likely won't match any existing entity key identifiers, hence the `None` result causing the error you see.

Since the info you have available is the value of an entity's property (the `email` value) you probably want to perform a query, something along these lines:

```
results = User.query(User.email == message[0]).fetch(limit=1)
if results:
   user = results[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sadly, this did not work. So I understand that `.get_by_id()` is wrong. I tried using email for id but then realized it only supports int values... (I forgot to delete that before posting the question). But even if I try to get the query results through `results = User.query(User.email == message[0]).fetch(limit=1)` The list is always empty (results[0], index is out of bounds.) I manually created a few entities in gcloud datastore console for testing. Also `user = User.get_by_id(5749328048029696)
        self.response.write("\n" + user.email)` returns NoneType exception

Comment: Do you see a valid email string in `message[0]`? Do you see results if querying by GQL for that same message string?

Comment: So I figure out what was wrong. So there seems to be an issue with the way Google Cloud SDK is set up on my computer. When running the same code on the google servers rather than on my network everything seems to work properly. Thanks for all your help.